# SharePoint 2013 - Configuring Workflow Manager

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

I am attempting to configure the workflow manager. I have a SQL DB and SP server.  In  WF Manager Configuration Wizard, when I enter the name of my SQL DB into the SQL server instance field and test the connection, I receive a check mark. However, if I check the "Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance", and test the connection message, I receive an error message "Failure in connecting to SQL Server".

What could cause the test connection to fail when I enable SSL connection? As long as I do not enable SSL, the test connection pass.

I have a very simple environment. Nothing complex. 1 - SQL Server and 1 SP server with SP Standard 2013 installed.

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your SQL Server has the login for the account under which you are running *Workflow Manager Configuration Wizard*.

## Step 1

Go into SQL Management Studio and add a new login for the account running *Workflow Manager Configuration*.

[image]

## Step 2

Enter your connection string in the *Workflow Manager Configuration* and test it to see if it works.

[image]

---

This might look simple in retrospective, but took me a day to figure out. I wish the error message was more elaborate than a useless "Failure in connecting to SQL Server".

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and it works when I put the full name of the SQL